# Problemas de asincronismo en Angular en una función al llamar API

Tags: javascript, angular, promesas, async-await

Tengo un problema en Angular con una función al llamar dos APIs. Tengo una función en la cual ejecuto dos llamadas a las APIs en diferentes momentos.

Éste es el método que está llamando, en donde en el método `seleccionarMat()` y `esNi()` llaman a APIs diferentes. Pero en vez de ejecutar estos métodos primero carga los `console.log()`.

```
onCrear(){
     this.seleccionarMat();
     this.esNi(this.MCodigo);

     console.log(this.tipoEs);
      console.log(this.form);
}
```

Aquí están las funciones que llaman a las APIs, de las cuales obtengo los valores que quiero mostrar en la función:

```
async seleccionarMat(){
  ( this.solicitudServicio.obtenerMatApi(this.sx)).subscribe((informacion:EsMa)=>{
     informacion.Response.map( (item)=>{
      this.form =  item.mxd
 

    });


 });


 }

 async esNi(codigo:number){
  (await this.solicitudServicio.obtenerApiNi(codigo)).subscribe( (informacion:EsNi)=>{
      informacion.Response.map(async (item)=>{
       this.tipoEs =   item.esN
       

     });


  });
   
 }
```

Pongo también cómo llamo a las APIs:

```
async esNi( mx:number){
    return   this.http.get<Es>(`${environment.url_api}/api/ruta?mx=${mx}`);
  }

  seleccionarMat( sx:number){
    return  this.http.get<EsMat>(`${environment.url_api}/api/ruta/mat?sxdoc_codigo=${sxd}`);
  }
```

Entonces:

- ¿Cómo puedo hacer que estas funciones se realicen primero y después se ejecute los `console.log()` con los resultados que traigo de las APIs?
- ¿Por qué se está cargando primero los `console.log()` y luego recién se ejecutan las APIs?

Creo que tiene algo que ver con el asincronismo
de JavaScript, pero desconozco cómo realizarlo en Angular.

Comment: No debes usar async/await con observables, ya que es algo distinto a las promesas y no obtendrás los resultados que esperas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en angular hay muchas formas de controlar el asincronismo de una función, la que veo mas limpia y ordenada es implementando el pipe **finalize**, el cual nos permite esperar hasta que la subscripción a algún evento finalice.

```
public onCrear(): void {
    this.seleccionarMat();
}

private seleccionarMat(): void {
    this.solicitudServicio.obtenerMatApi(this.sx)
        .pipe(finalize(() => {
            console.log('Paso 1');
            this.esNi(9999);
        }))
        .subscribe((informacion: EsMa) => {
            informacion.Response.map((item) => {
                this.form = item.mxd;
            });
        });
}

private esNi(codigo: number): void {
    this.solicitudServicio.obtenerApiNi(codigo)
        .pipe(finalize(() => {
            console.log('Paso 2');
            this.mostrarConsoleLog();
        }))
        .subscribe((informacion: EsNi) => {
            informacion.Response.map(async (item) => {
                this.tipoEs = item.esN;
            });
        });
}

private mostrarConsoleLog(): void {
    console.log('Paso 3');
    console.log(this.tipoEs);
    console.log(this.form);
}
```

Con este código no es necesario implementar un async/await queda mas limpio, ordenado y entendible el paso a paso con su respectiva dependencia y lo que se veria en consola seria lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema, y el de la mayoría que empieza con las peticiones a APIs es el tema de la asincronía. El código se va ejecutando línea a línea de forma síncrona, pero, las peticiones a las APIs son asíncronas, porque no tienen porqué haber dado respuesta en el mismo instante que la función es llamada. Es por eso que debemos usar el dúo `async/await`, que permite al sistema indicar que la función debe esperar a estar completa para seguir la ejecución.

En tu caso, has indicado el async, pero no el await, por lo que la función no puede ver qué parte del código debe esperar a ser ejecutada.

```
async esNi( mx:number){
    return await this.http.get<Es>(`${environment.url_api}/api/ruta?mx=${mx}`);
  }

  seleccionarMat( sx:number){
    return await this.http.get<EsMat>(`${environment.url_api}/api/ruta/mat?sxdoc_codigo=${sxd}`);
  }
```

Añadiendo `await` delante del return, debería funcionarte.

Comment: Async/await asume promesas, pero aquí estamos trabajando con observables

Answer (score 0):

**¿Por qué se está cargando primero los `console.log()` y luego recién se ejecutan las APIs?**

Cuando llamas a dos funciones definidas como asíncronas (`async`) su ejecución no se realiza en ese momento, si no que la llamada devuelve una promesa que será resuelta al finalizar su ejecución.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que estas funciones se realicen primero y después se ejecute los `console.log()` con los resultados que traigo de las APIs?**

Debes usar [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) para hacer lo que deseas cuando el trabajo de las funciones **ha concluido**:

```
onCrear() {
    this.seleccionarMat().then(() => {
        /* Cuando finalice el trabajo mostramos el valor esperado */
        console.log(this.form);
    });
    this.esNi(this.MCodigo).then(() => {
        /* Cuando finalice el trabajo mostramos el valor esperado */
        console.log(this.tipoEs);
    });
}
```

Si usaras un `return item.mxd;` y `return item.esN;` dentro de tus funciones, entonces podrías hacer:

```
onCrear() {
    this.seleccionarMat().then(resultado => {
        /* Mostramos el valor devuelto por la función */
        console.log(resultado);
    });
    this.esNi(this.MCodigo).then(resultado => {
        /* Mostramos el valor devuelto por la función */
        console.log(resultado);
    });
}
```

---

Si quieres mostrar el resultado solo cuando ambas finalicen, entonces puedes usar [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled):

```
onCrear() {
    const promesa1 = this.seleccionarMat();
    const promesa2 = this.esNi(this.MCodigo);
    Promise.allSettled([ promesa1, promesa2 ]).then((resultados) => {
        /* Ambos valores están disponibles para ser mostrados */
        console.log(this.form);
        console.log(this.tipoEs);
        /* Vemos el resultado de cada consulta (fulfilled o rejected) */
        resultados.forEach((resultado) => console.log(resultado.status))
    });
}
```